# A 'const' initializer in an ambient context must be a string or numeric literal or literal enum reference

Tags: nativescript

Just upgrade Nativescript to version 7 and getting the errors below, not sure why nativescript is throwing this error.

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^10.2.4",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^10.1.7",
    "@nativescript/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "js-base64": "^2.5.2",
    "nativescript-admob": "^4.0.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^5.0.6",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "^2.4.3",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.11",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^10.6.3",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "^7.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^9.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^9.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.4",
    "@nativescript/android": "7.0.1",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^10.1.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "^7.0.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^10.2.1",
    "@schematics/angular": "^10.2.1",
    "@schematics/update": "^0.11.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
```

I also tried typescript 4 but that yields more errors.

Anyone come across this issue below:

[image]

Comment: Hi! have you found the solution to this. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `tsconfig.json` contains

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

it appears to be coming in by default if you're generating a new project but is not being added during update process. Adding it fixed the issue for me and now I'm able to compile the app with no issues.

Below is an example of my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "platforms"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a Nativescript bug. The solution was implemented 5 days ago but there was no new release since 11 days. In the meantime you can fix it yourself. Here is the solution:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/9136/commits/619fd49186f58d4d11d0554458af1210108c89d1

Comment: Does this mean everytime i do a ns clean and npm install i have to always make these changes for now?

Comment: I'm sorry for late response, I missed your comment somehow. The answer to your question is yes, but this is fixed in the latest release already as you can see here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/packages/core/platform/index.d.ts